# Javascript animation only working for one item in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am practicing `Javascript` and `HTML`, I came across this list [item/adpter like we call them in android](https://codepen.io/virgilpana/pen/RNYQwB). its great but I having challenges. I am adding them to my `div` programically like this

```
 $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../public/allevents/"+pn,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('Events Response::'+data);
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                        for(event in obj.events){
                            console.log('Event:'+event);
                            $("#eventHolder").append(
                                '<div class="make-3D-space">'
                                    +'<div id="product-card">'
                                     +'<div class="product-front">'
                                      +'<div class="shadow"></div>'
                                    +'<img src="'+'..'+obj.events[event].image+'" alt="" />'
                                +'<div class="image_overlay"></div>'
                                +'<div id="view_details">View details</div>'
                                +'<div class="stats">'         
                                +'<div class="stats-container">'
                            +'<span class="product_price">FREE</span>'
                            +'<span class="product_name">'+obj.events[event].title+'</span>'    
                            +'<p>'+moment(obj.events[event].starts).utc().format('DD MMM, YY [at] hh:mm A')+'</p>'                                            
                            +'<div class="product-options">'
                         +'<strong>LOCATION</strong>'
                        +'<span>'+obj.events[event].address+'</span>'
                        +'</div>'                       
                      +'</div>'                         
                    +'</div>'
                    +'</div>' 
                    +'</div>'  
                    +'</div>');
                        }
                    addViewListenersToadapters();
                    },
                     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                      console.log('Events Response::'+xhr.responseText);
                       //swal("Error", "Error deleting, try again", "error");
                    }

                }
        )
```

They are adding just fine. But the expand animation is only working for the first item, from my knowledge it is because the `items` use a single `id` so `Javascript` finds the first item and applies the animation to it. I have the idea, I could change the `ids` of the items when adding them but this `static` `javascript`that does the animation has `static ids` so it wont work either way

```
function addViewListenersToadapters(){
$(document).ready(function(){

// Lift card and show stats on Mouseover
$('#product-card').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animate');
        $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');            
     }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('animate');         
        $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
}); 

// Flip card to the back side
$('#view_details').click(function(){        
    $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
    $('#product-card').addClass('flip-10');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#product-card').removeClass('flip-10').addClass('flip90').find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 80 , 1, function(){
            $('#product-front, #product-front div.shadow').hide();          
        });
    }, 50);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip190');
        $('#product-back').show().find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 90 , 0);
        setTimeout(function(){              
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip180').find('div.shadow').hide();                        
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#product-card').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');         
                $('#cx, #cy').addClass('s1');
                setTimeout(function(){$('#cx, #cy').addClass('s2');}, 100);
                setTimeout(function(){$('#cx, #cy').addClass('s3');}, 200);             
                $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');                
            }, 100);
        }, 100);            
    }, 150);            
});         

// Flip card back to the front side
$('#flip-back').click(function(){       

    $('#product-card').removeClass('flip180').addClass('flip190');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip90');

        $('#product-back div.shadow').css('opacity', 0).fadeTo( 100 , 1, function(){
            $('#product-back, #product-back div.shadow').hide();
            $('#product-front, #product-front div.shadow').show();
        });
    }, 50);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip-10');
        $('#product-front div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 100 , 0);
        setTimeout(function(){                      
            $('#product-front div.shadow').hide();
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip-10').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');      
            $('#cx, #cy').removeClass('s1 s2 s3');          
        }, 100);            
    }, 150);            

}); 


/* ----  Image Gallery Carousel   ---- */

var carousel = $('#carousel ul');
var carouselSlideWidth = 335;
var carouselWidth = 0;  
var isAnimating = false;

// building the width of the casousel
$('#carousel li').each(function(){
    carouselWidth += carouselSlideWidth;
});
$(carousel).css('width', carouselWidth);

// Load Next Image
$('div.carouselNext').on('click', function(){
    var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
    var newLeft = currentLeft + carouselSlideWidth;
    if(newLeft == carouselWidth || isAnimating === true){return;}
    $('#carousel ul').css({'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
                           "transition": "300ms ease-out"
                         });
    isAnimating = true;
    setTimeout(function(){isAnimating = false;}, 300);          
});

// Load Previous Image
$('div.carouselPrev').on('click', function(){
    var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
    var newLeft = currentLeft - carouselSlideWidth;
    if(newLeft < 0  || isAnimating === true){return;}
    $('#carousel ul').css({'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
                           "transition": "300ms ease-out"
                         });
    isAnimating = true;
    setTimeout(function(){isAnimating = false;}, 300);          
});
});
```

How Can I fix this? Again am a learner I do not know my way around it.

Comment: Demo here https://codepen.io/fatih-erol/pen/MqrGEm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the #product-cart div

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "../public/allevents/"+pn,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('Events Response::'+data);
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                    for(event in obj.events){
                        console.log('Event:'+event);
                        $("#eventHolder").append(
                            '<div class="make-3D-space">'
                                +'<div id="product-card" class="product-card">'
                                 +'<div class="product-front">'
                                  +'<div class="shadow"></div>'
                                +'<img src="'+'..'+obj.events[event].image+'" alt="" />'
                            +'<div class="image_overlay"></div>'
                            +'<div id="view_details">View details</div>'
                            +'<div class="stats">'         
                            +'<div class="stats-container">'
                        +'<span class="product_price">FREE</span>'
                        +'<span class="product_name">'+obj.events[event].title+'</span>'    
                        +'<p>'+moment(obj.events[event].starts).utc().format('DD MMM, YY [at] hh:mm A')+'</p>'                                            
                        +'<div class="product-options">'
                     +'<strong>LOCATION</strong>'
                    +'<span>'+obj.events[event].address+'</span>'
                    +'</div>'                       
                  +'</div>'                         
                +'</div>'
                +'</div>' 
                +'</div>'  
                +'</div>');
                    }
                addViewListenersToadapters();
                },
                 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log('Events Response::'+xhr.responseText);
                   //swal("Error", "Error deleting, try again", "error");
                }

            }
    )
```

and don't use the $(document).ready() inside function called async, it will never triggered.

```
function addViewListenersToadapters(){


    // Lift card and show stats on Mouseover
    $('.product-card').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('animate');
            $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');            
         }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('animate');         
            $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
    }); 

    // Flip card to the back side
    $('#view_details').click(function(){        
        $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
        $('#product-card').addClass('flip-10');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip-10').addClass('flip90').find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 80 , 1, function(){
                $('#product-front, #product-front div.shadow').hide();          
            });
        }, 50);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip190');
            $('#product-back').show().find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 90 , 0);
            setTimeout(function(){              
                $('#product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip180').find('div.shadow').hide();                        
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#product-card').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');         
                    $('#cx, #cy').addClass('s1');
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#cx, #cy').addClass('s2');}, 100);
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#cx, #cy').addClass('s3');}, 200);             
                    $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');                
                }, 100);
            }, 100);            
        }, 150);            
    });         

    // Flip card back to the front side
    $('#flip-back').click(function(){       

        $('#product-card').removeClass('flip180').addClass('flip190');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip90');

            $('#product-back div.shadow').css('opacity', 0).fadeTo( 100 , 1, function(){
                $('#product-back, #product-back div.shadow').hide();
                $('#product-front, #product-front div.shadow').show();
            });
        }, 50);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip-10');
            $('#product-front div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 100 , 0);
            setTimeout(function(){                      
                $('#product-front div.shadow').hide();
                $('#product-card').removeClass('flip-10').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');      
                $('#cx, #cy').removeClass('s1 s2 s3');          
            }, 100);            
        }, 150);            

    }); 


    /* ----  Image Gallery Carousel   ---- */

    var carousel = $('#carousel ul');
    var carouselSlideWidth = 335;
    var carouselWidth = 0;  
    var isAnimating = false;

    // building the width of the casousel
    $('#carousel li').each(function(){
        carouselWidth += carouselSlideWidth;
    });
    $(carousel).css('width', carouselWidth);

    // Load Next Image
    $('div.carouselNext').on('click', function(){
        var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
        var newLeft = currentLeft + carouselSlideWidth;
        if(newLeft == carouselWidth || isAnimating === true){return;}
        $('#carousel ul').css({'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
                               "transition": "300ms ease-out"
                             });
        isAnimating = true;
        setTimeout(function(){isAnimating = false;}, 300);          
    });

    // Load Previous Image
    $('div.carouselPrev').on('click', function(){
        var currentLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($(carousel).css("left")));
        var newLeft = currentLeft - carouselSlideWidth;
        if(newLeft < 0  || isAnimating === true){return;}
        $('#carousel ul').css({'left': "-" + newLeft + "px",
                               "transition": "300ms ease-out"
                             });
        isAnimating = true;
        setTimeout(function(){isAnimating = false;}, 300);          
    });
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful and little did I know the solution was simple. Thanks.